# Does virtual memory mapping fragmentation cause performance issue?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I have an application where I start by creating large anonymous mapping (of the order of 4MB) each using linux `mmap` system call.

Then during process execution, in order to release memory as soon as possible I was thinking about unmapping smaller chunk of memory so that the virtual memory mapping that initially was a large block will result in being fragmented.

May this cause performance issue due to virtual memory translation table fragmentation or does the kernel use smart strategy to avoid that? May I do not mind about the fragmentation of the virtual memory mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Short answer:* Not really unless you're allocating tons and tons of non contiguous regions of minimum granularity (ie. 4096 bytes) at random.

---

*Long answer:* Kind of,

On modern architectures you have several levels of virtual memory maps (or page tables, whichever term you prefer), with 64 bit architectures, it's common to have 4 level memory maps for a 48 bit address space (Intel's upcoming extensions will add another level which allows fragmenting a 4096 byte page into 256 byte pages). Each time you allocate a page in a region where no map yet exists, the kernel has to allocate a new (usually **physically** contiguous; note the emphasis, this is a rather expensive operation in relative terms) chunk of memory to hold the translation map for that region for that memory space. I'll avoid arch specific terms and just call them `L0 -> L1 -> L2 -> L3` with `L0` being the root map that represents that virtual memory space. This will vary with page size granularity and with different operating systems or architectures (for example Linux has superpages).

Now, if your new mapping is at L3 level, and has an L3 page table, a new mapping will just involve changing an entry in that region to indicate the translation. If there's no L3 page table, a new L3 page table has to be allocated, and entered into the L2 page table. And so on down to the L0 page table.

Few quick notes:

- Every time a mapping is changed there is usually a TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer; a hardware cache used by the MMU for VM->Phys translations) invalidation penalty (whether manual or automatic).
- Some pages may not need all 4 stages of translation, a translation level has a specific size, so a superpage is usually a page that for example uses the L2 page table entry to map the entire chunk of that VM space to physical space (this means only 3 levels of translation are needed).
- Various architectures use different methods for reducing the penalty of TLB trashing (ie. PCID on x86_64; In fact some meltdown mitigations like KPTI caused performance regressions without it).
- Speaking of meltdown, some ranges of memory may have the kernel or trampoline mappings or exception vectors. Those are reserved by the OS. On 64 bit systems pre-Spectre/Meltdown, it was common for the kernel to keep itself mapped in every page table. A lot of ARM processors have a dedicated mechanism for it called split page tables (TTBR0/TTBR1; Translation Table Base Register 0/1).
- One example of the above is the Linux VDSO (Virtual Dynamic Shared Object) which is a mapping created by the kernel. The Darwin (OSX/iOS) counterpart to that is the commpage (Common page). This usually has read-only code shared by every single process in the system and has things current time (to reduce the cost of a syscall, `gettimeofday` may read it from the VDSO or use a VDSO trampoline to read it).
- Of course all of the above varies depending on the architecture and the OS you're using and the version of the OS you're using, since virtual memory managers often use a variety of techniques to ensure fragmentation does not occur. **If you request lots of small fixed mappings at random however, yes you will effectively be bypassing a lot of it, causing performance issues.**

Comment: I am trying to understand. Suppose I make an mmap and it entirely fit in a L3 page table (for examples virtual memory page 1 to 10 is associated to physical memory A to J). Then if I unmap virtual memory pages 2, 5, 8 for example, the kernel will not create an L2 page table, because 2, 5, 8 are inside the previously allocated L3 page table. Correct? (1)

Comment: Nevertheless, the physical memory associated to 2, 5, 8 (B,E,H) may be reused by other process no? (2)

Comment: Does not the kernel allocate physical memory on a page fault? What is the granularity of a page fault? Is it an entire memory mapping (for example if I first access a byte in 1, the kernel fault 1-10 and reserve A to J), or does it only reserve one page of physical memory? (3)

Comment: Also thank you for your detailed explanation Kristina :).

Comment: Last time I checked (Linux 2.6), new binaries were not mapped so yes initially every read from a new page caused a page fault, that was down to the disk/block cache layer however. With ASLR now days it's hard to tell since page tables are hard to share without compromising security, as well as the requirement for code on such pages to be fully PIC (Only PC-relative, aka requiring no relocations. which is how the VDSO works).

Comment: "Does not the kernel allocate physical memory on a page fault?" -> It depends on many factors, usually the VMM uses a freelist to grab page table memory from, so strictly speaking, it does not allocate it, there's too many reasons for why allocating memory while handling a fault is a bad idea to put it in a comment. It's a common topic covered in OS development books, I may suggest reading about it, they likely explain it much better than I do.

Comment: Also, if I answered your question, would you mind marking it as such? Thank you! Virtual memory management is a complex topic and the answer just skims over some common areas related to it. One good and more informative resource is https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging

Comment: Of course your answer fit my question! Once again thank you.